# the relationship between $f^{-1}(x)$ and $x$

Tags: calculus

A elementary question here. If I have 
$$f(x)<x\quad\forall\,\,x\in (0,1).$$

Can I deduce $f^{-1}(x)>x$ for $x\ne 0,x\ne 1$?

If yes, could anyone show me how?

Comment: Do you mean the same $x$ in $f(x) < x$ as you do in $f^{-1}(x) > x$? Meaning, are you looking for $f^{-1}(x) > x > f(x)$?

Comment: yes i mean the same $x$.

Comment: $f(y)<y=f^{-1}(f(y))$ for all $y\in (0,1)$. Then label $x=f(y)$ and you're done.

Comment: yes, I'm a bit clearer with this answer now. Will take another think tomorrow. 1:31 AM here...

Comment: Use another letter, as $y$, for  numbers in the range of $f$, i.e., in the domain of $f^{-1}$. Note that the subset $f^{-1}(\{y\})\subset\ ]0,1[\ $ is defined even if $f$ is not injective, and $x>y$ holds for all $x$ in this subset.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter, what do you mean by $f^{-1}({y})\subset (0,1)$ is defined even if $f$ is not injective?

Answer (score 4):

Apply your condition $f(y) < y$ to $y:=f^{-1}(x)$, and you immediately get 
$$x = f(f^{-1}(x))<f^{-1}(x)$$

Answer (score 3):

Think in terms of the graph of $f$. If you know that $f(x)<x$ for all $x$, then the graph of $f$ lies below the line $y=x$ (because that line is the graph of $g(x)=x$, and you are told that $f(x)<g(x)$).

But the graph of $f^{-1}$ is the reflection of the graph of $f$ across the line $y=x$. That means the graph of $f^{-1}$ lies *above* the line $y=x$, which is equivalent (much as before) to the statement that $f^{-1}(x)>x$.

Comment: ...pictorially what you suggested is okay, but i need a elementary proof without the picture and without knowing the definition of 'graph'.

Answer (score 1):

Think of $f$ as a sender. $f(x)$ is the element that this $f$  sends $x$ to. 
Your hypothesis says that the sender $f$ has the shrinking property: it sends any $x$ to something smaller than it. Now $f^{-1}$ is a function that reverse-engineers $f$. Given a $y$ it treats it as an element sent by $f$ and tries to figure out which one was sent to it by $f$. So it hs to be bigger than the $y$: that is $f^{-1}(y)>y$. (Moral: sometimes it is better to use different symbols).

Comment: um i quite like your thought and intuitively what you suggested make sense. But can we make the maths more precise in this case?

Comment: @math101: You seem to have trouble making precise from the idea I gave. So I decided to check on your profile to find at what level I should explain. I found that you are not a some pre-calculus student but one who talks about compact riemannian manifold, and Lie algebras. I am confused about what your mathematical level is!

Answer (score 0):

the domain of $f$ is $(0,1)$ and the range of $f$ is a subset of $(0,1)$ because of the constraint $f(x) < x \text{ for } 0 < x < 1.$  let $y$ be a point in the range of $f$  and $f(x) = y, x = f^{-1}(y).$

now, $$ f(x)< x $$ is equivalent to $$ y < f^{-1}(y) \text{ or } f^{-1}(y) > y.$$  what we have is $$f^{-1}(y) > y \quad \forall y \in range(f)  $$ and $range(f)$ is not necessarily $(0,1).$